# Random Forest on large xdf files without reading into a dataframe

Tags: r, random-forest

Is there a way to run random forest on large (about 10gb) xdf (revolution R format) files? Obviously I can try rxReadXdf and covert it to a dataframe...but my machine only has 8gb ram and I may be dealing with even larger data sets in the future. For example, using the foreach loop, I will like to run 1000 trees on my quad core machine:

```
#'train.xdf" is a 10gb training data set
rf<- foreach(ntree=rep(250, 4), .combine=combine, 
             .packages='randomForest') %do%
    randomForest(amount2~.,data="train", ntree=ntree, importance=TRUE,
                 na.action=na.omit, replace=FALSE)
```

But randomForest is unable to take in "train" (an xdf) file. Is there a way to run random forest directly on xdf without reading into a dataframe?

Cheers,
agsub

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but I have never worked with xdf files. I would instead try to split the data into smaller chunks, train random forests on those and build a final model on the best features from all chunks combined. It is quite cumbersome though.

Comment: Ya that's probably the way I will go for now

Comment: The bright side of it is that if data analysis was easy I wouldn't have a job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not without changing the R code that underlies the **randomForest** package and even then it may not be possible as the FORTRAN routines that underlay the RF method probably require all the data to be held in memory. You may be best served in general getting a stack more RAM for you machine or finding some bigger workstations / clusters of machines to run this problem on.

(Why do you want 1000 random forests?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Revolution file format, but it is possible to run `randomForest` on several subsets of your data and then combine the results into a single ensemble.

Comment: +1 Good point; I was going to make the same point in my Answer but wasn't sure if that would mean loading all the data into RAM to generate a subset; Given what the OP says, even that may not be possible on their machine, but must have been possible to create the file in the first place.

Comment: Yep, I guess the best way for me is to split up the data and do random forest a few times. The xdf file basically creates a virtual memory dump on the hdd, you can think of it as virtual memory that R can access quickly. Also, I made a correction to my qn, is trying to run 1000 trees, not 1000 random forest. Thanks for your help guys =)

Answer (score 2):

Random forests are usually trained depth-first, that is training on the current node, and then recursively train on the child nodes. This requires the entire data-set to be held in memory.

To overcome this limitation, I wrote the random forest training framework to handle the data incrementally (sometimes called 'online), never holding more than one entry at a time. This requires a breadth-first construction of the trees, and requires calculating the purity statistics using online algorithms. Each level of the tree sees the data exactly once, so your xdf file need not be stored in memory, but will be read D times, where D is the maximum depth of the tree.

I know this is probably not helpful, because you can't change the given code, but maybe you'll find implementation of those online versions of the algorithm (try [Amir Safar's group](http://www.ymer.org/amir/software/online-random-forests/))

Answer (score 1):

To overcome memory limitations, use:

```
max_size_of_pagefiles <- 60000 # in MBs
memory.limit(size = max_size_of_pagefiles)
```

I use an SSD as a drive to store the pagefile and the amount of free space can be used as memory (the following example works on Windows):

```
freespace <- as.numeric(gsub("Total # of free bytes        : ", "", 
   system2('fsutil', 'volume diskfree c:', stdout = TRUE)[1]))/(1024*1024)
memory.limit(size = freespace*0.9)
```